# Show that for all integers $n\geq 2$ that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \geq \frac{3n}{2n+1}$

Tags: summation, induction, natural-numbers

It can be done with induction by comparing $\frac{3n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and $\frac{3(n+1)}{2(n+1)+1}$, but I would like a better alternative since this one involves a lot of expanding and is just algebra, and it's not very impressive in my opinion.

Comment: Define "impressive"...imo, a simple, straightforward demonstration, even if it is a little messy algebrawise, is very impressive.

Comment: @Ansper it is a nice inequality... "Easier" options like $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \ge \int_1^n\frac{1}{x^2} dx$ give you worse bounds.

Comment: @DonAntonio maybe I should've used "interesting" rather than "impressive"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know about generalized harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}=H_n^{(2)}$$ and its expansion is
$$H_n^{(2)}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ while
$$\frac{3n}{2n+1}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3}{4 n}+\frac{3}{8 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ So
$$\text{lhs - rhs}=\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{8
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which is always positive.

Comment: Poor fly! Never saw the cannon coming! Apart from that, +1.

Comment: You can certainly say that it is positive for $n$ large enough.

Comment: @Gary the $O(1/n^3)$ term can be presented more explicitly. I guess Claude Leibovici did not want to  loose focus of the main result.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, I am well aware about the enveloping property of this expansion. I just wanted to point out that, in its present form, the proof is incomplete.

Comment: @Gary Agreed! The induction proof the OP mentioned is probably the most instructive approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would begin plugging in values starting from 2 and going up. What we notice immediately is that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{1}{k^2})=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}...\frac{1}{k^2}$ which would ultimately have a limit of $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ as $k\to\infty$.

To prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{1}{k^2})\geq\frac{3n}{2n+1}$, simply need to prove that this fraction never exceeds $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Set up the expression and set it equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ like this:

$$
\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{3n}{2n+1}
$$

Through basic algebra, we get that $2n(\pi^2-9)-\pi=0$ which, through some more manipulation, shows that $n=\frac{-\pi^2}{2(\pi^2-9)}\approx-5.67...$. Because this is a negative number and the only solution to setting it equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we know that $n\geq2$ will never exceed $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ *& ergo* never be greater than $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{1}{k^2})$.

*QED qve* $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{1}{k^2})\geq\frac{3n}{2n+1}$

Comment: The limit of the series is not $2$ but rather $\frac{\pi^2}{6}=1.644934\ldots$.

Comment: I miscalculated. I'm rusty on my limits. I edited the post to fix the error. The math is ultimately the same idea, it's just that the zero is as a (wildly) different point. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: The sequence $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}$ never exceeds its limit either. The fact that neither $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}$ nor $\frac{3n}{2n+1}$ ever exceeds $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ does not imply anything about their magnitude when compared to each other. You can say that $\frac{3n}{2n+1}$ never exceeds $\frac{3}{2} < \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, so eventually $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}>\frac{3n}{2n+1}$. Can you see what I mean?